# Prove: two elements in the group of permutations satisfy A^2 = B^2 then A = B.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutation-cycles

How does one prove when two cycles in the group of permutations satisfy A^2 = B^2 that A = B?

I think the fact the inverses A_*A = e and A_ = A^(l-1) and A = A^(l+1) is useful. l is the length of the cycles A and B, l is odd.  Because V^2 is a cycle if and only if the length is odd.

I have a tendency to assume proofs have to be more complicated then they need to be.

Comment: transpositions?

Comment: In the initial statement, odd length wasn't specified. I think that restriction is necessary for the statement to be true.

Comment: @coffeemath I didn't specify that A, B, A^2, and B^2 were all cycles either.  I have to be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

We need to assume cycle lengths of $A,B$ are odd. Otherwise $(1,2,3,4)$ and $(1,4,3,2)$ have the same squares. Maybe you want all of $A,B,A^2,B^2$ to be cycles, then the lengths must be odd. [But that wasn't said in question]

Anyway first show if $A^2=B^2$ the $A,B$ have the same length, say $2n-1.$ Then since $A^{2n-1}=1$ [because cycle to length of cycle is 1] you have $A^{2n}=A.$ Similarly $B^{2n}=B.$ But then

$$A=A^{2n}=[A^2]^n=[B^2]^n=B^{2n}=B,$$
where in the middle we used assumption $A^2=B^2.$

Comment: But isn't this simply saying the identity function satisfies A^2 = B^2?  Since a cycle of one element can only be the identity (I think).

Comment: @JenniferClarke I see your issue-- but the problem itself says to assume $A^2=B^2$ and then show $A=B$ follows. So the conclusion of the problem is the two permutations are equal, i.e. one can say the identity function gives the relation between $A$ and $B.$ That relation was not *assumed* in the problem, but had to be derived.Also no assumption that the cycle was of only $1$ element was used.

Comment: How about A = A^(l + 1), where l is odd. (and l is the length of the cycle).  So A = A^(2n + 1 + 1) = A^(2n + 2) = A^(2(n+1)) = [A^2]^(n+1) = [B^2]^(n+1) = B^(2(n+1)) = B^(2n + 1 + 1) = B^(l + 1) = B.  Now I'm wondering if I can assume the B has l length like A, because I like making things complicated.

Comment: @JenniferClarke Your argument in comment is just a shifted version of mine (notation for cycle length different). About assuming B has same length as A: If $A=(x_1,x_2,\cdot x_l)$ when squared gives $(x_1,x_3,\cdots,x_l,x_2,x_4,\cdots x_{l-1})$ so same length as A. When we assume squares equal, we therefore assume lengths equal also.